Rear derailleur to Cog contact perimeter
When the chain in the biggest rear cog.
The chain has to much contact perimeter with the biggest cog. It also have not the the "right sound". (I'm not sure, that I explain it clear enough. I expect it to be in a position as on image with red arrow.)
Before that I replaced Microshift shifter by Shimano Revoshift. I don't remember if that issue was before. I assume that Microshift and Shimano are interchangeable on old Dahon bicycle.
What needs to be done ?

shorten the chain
cable tension (I believe it's not the case)
adjustment screws (I didn't find a third screw, which can change an angle)
to replace rear derailleur or shifter.
something else ?

Current situation

Desired spacing | chain/cog position.

Another image of "desired spacing"


How did you come to that "desired" position? The chain gap and bend in the derailleur cable seem to indicate that it's actually the "desired" position.

@delphinus, This is what I see on other bicycles and because of extra sound.

@delphinus Although the "desired position" indicated is a little extreme, it is indeed a step in the right direction. In the "current situation" photo, you can see that the upper jockey wheel is pretty much intersecting with the cassette cog.

@delphinus I had a bit similar on another Dahon bicycle, after replacing the rear derailleur to one with a short cage. The reason for the replacement was that a long cage with 20" tire, chain is very close to the road and makes it dirty faster.

I have seen this happen where the derailleur hanger has bent and instead of correcting the problem, the deralleur has been adjusted to compensate as far as possible to get the gears working. Check hanger alignment or have a shop do it.
I have also seen this happen where some bump has moved the derailleur mounting plate: slacken off the 5mm allen slightly to check it is resting against the stop on the hanger.
The derailleur may be showing its age and a replacement with the "B"-screw adjustment would be a good option, potentially allowing use of a wider range cassette in the future, though it's a shame to waste your custom paintwork.

That is a very interesting way to refer to the paint!

@Noise, Regarding the hanger alignment, you mean the hanger plane to be aligned with cassette plane ? On the rear derailleur, there is some inner spring which can move the cage, I wonder how this spring can be triggered.

@MichaelD Aligning the planes, as you say, is what i mean. It is done with the derailleur removed
